# ¿Como iniciar Microsoft SQL Server 2014 en Windows 10?

Tags: sql-server

Como iniciar Microsoft SQL Server 2014 en Windows 10, ya que aparece instalado dentro de los programas pero no encuentro el icono de acceso directo para iniciarlo

Comment: @Elenasys y demás, por favor **dejen de votar a cierre preguntas por causas equivocadas**.

Answer (score 2):

Se instala como servicio.

Para verificarlo ejecutá

> Herramientas Administrativas/Servicios

Y verifica que el servicio esté corriendo como se ve en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por otro lado para acceder al servidor, tenés que usar **SQL Server Management Studio** o un cliente similar.